# How to Resolve the Maximum Rejected Threshold was reached while reading data from SRCTable to TGTTable using ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am getting below mentioned error while loading data from synapse src Table to synapse TGT Table.

SQLServerException: Query aborted-- the maximum reject threshold (0 rows) was reached while reading from an external source: 1 rows rejected out of total 1 rows processed.\nColumn ordinal: 26, Expected data type: VARCHAR(255) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT

Requesting you to suggest how to overcome the above mentioned issue.

Regards,
Ashok

Answer (score 0):

The error may be due to data truncation from the column 26 of your source file.

As a first check I would suggest increasing the destination table column from VARCHAR(255) to VARCHAR(MAX) and then try to run this copy again.

`ALTER TABLE TGT ALTER COLUMN [column 29] VARCHAR(MAX);`

If it successes, you can easily run a max on that destination table column to determine how big it should be.

`SELECT MAX(LEN([column 29])) FROM TGT`

Some related reading about polybase copy:
https://medium.com/microsoftazure/azure-synapse-data-load-using-polybase-or-copy-command-from-vnet-protected-azure-storage-da8aa6a9ac68